# Understanding of a line of code in Laravel routing

Tags: php, oop, laravel, routes, laravel-routing

after learning procedural I'm trying to learning OOP in PHP, and after studying some theory I'm trying to apply it studing the use of the Laravel framework.
I've found on my book this part of code, for routing, but I can't really understand it in OOP.

If I'm not wrong, the first part seems to me a static method of a 'Route' class, but then I find the second part
'->where('id','[0-9]+');' that seems dynamic and relative to an instance and is confusing me.

Can someone please help me understanding?

```
Route::get('cats/{id}', function($id){
return "Cat #$id";
})->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

Comment: Simply, `Route::get()` returns an object (probably an instance of `Route`) that has a method `where()`. See http://laravel.com/api/source-class-Illuminate.Routing.Route.html#309-323 (though I can't find `Route::get()` anywhere)

Comment: @Phil I'm assuming he's also asking about the [0-9]+ part. Seems like a regex something.

Comment: thanks @Phil it makes sense, but can't find too get() method.

Andrewp No, I know regular expressions

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`If I'm not wrong, the first part seems to me a static method of a 'Route' class`, Sorry but you are wrong here. Actually `Laravel` provides `Facade` class for each component and here `Route` is a `Facade` of underlying `Router` class. This is how that `Facade` class looks like:

```
<?php namespace Illuminate\Support\Facades;

/**
 * @see \Illuminate\Routing\Router
 */
class Route extends Facade {

    /**
     * Get the registered name of the component.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor() { return 'router'; }

}
```

You may noticed that, it contains only one method and it returns the `original/underlying` class name that contains the method, actually it's the `key` name using which the class is added into the `IoC` container. So, `Laravel` behind the scene, makes an instance of that `Illuminate/Routing/Router.php` class from the `IoC` container and calls the `method`, it's may looks unclear to you but it's a little tricky and it's not possible to answer in more details here but you may visit [Laravel facade](http://laravel.com/docs/facades) and get a better explanation of it.

So, finally, `Laravel` calls `get()` method from the `Router.php` class and it returns an instance of `Route` class/object and the `where` method of `Route` class then get called using method chaining (`PHP-5` feature), that's all. Read the source code of classes, you'll get a better idea.

Check the `Illuminate\Support\Facades` folder, you can find so many facade classes which are actually a wrapper over it's original class/component. Also check out the [IoC container](http://laravel.com/docs/ioc) in `Laravel`'s documentation, it's necessary to get a clear idea of it to work with Laravel framework.

Comment: This is very interesting, and a great answer.  Nice one.